# Compact subgroup and quotient implies compactness?

Tags: compactness, topological-groups

Let $G$ be a topological group with $K \le G$ a compact subgroup such that $G/K$ is compact. Is $G$ compact, too?

Comment: Cannot we write $G$ as the continuous image of $K \times G/K$?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I tried that first. But you have to choose continuously representatives for the cosets of $G/K$. I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Is the quotient a closed map? If so, use a standard result on perfect maps I proved today on this site.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Yeah, it is a closed map. Can you link your result?

Comment: Can you show closedness?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$q: G \rightarrow G/K$ is a perfect map: continuous, all fibres are homeomorphic to $K$, hence compact, $q$ is closed (I take this on faith from the OP). We then apply [this standard fact on perfect maps](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2195964/4280) (and my answer for a proof sketch) to conclude compactness of $G$.

Comment: The closedness is equivalent to $AK$ being closed for $A\subseteq G$ closed. For that, if $x\notin AK$, the compact set $xK$ is disjoint from $A$, so $UK\cap A=\emptyset$ for some open $U\ni x$ by the tube lemma. Hence $U\cap AK=\emptyset$, too.

Comment: @Hanno thx :) but tube lemma? that is for Cartesian products? But I think I could show it, using nets.

Comment: The multiplication map $G\times K\to G$, $(x,k)\mapsto xk$, is homeomorphic to the projection $G\times K\to G$ by means of $(x,k)\leftrightarrow (xk,k)$. The tube lemma gives the closedness of the projection, so the multiplication is closed, too. Hmm, ok, this renders the rest of the proof above unnecessary.